# Restrict Oracle from creating Compilation error Procedures

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, procedure

I want to know if there is a way to make **Oracle not create** a **Procedure/Function** if it has an **error** of any kind.

Comment: [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html) (commercial product) has an option to do this. Internally it generates a temporary name and only creates the specified object following successful compilation. The process is transparent so in effect invalid objects don't get created. Possibly there are other products with a similar feature.

Comment: Bear in mind, if you are trying to load up multiple objects (especially packages) that may have interdependencies, then a compile error on one might get resolved once all objects are created if you subsequently compile the schema. If, however, you drop them on the fly - you may have a difficult time doing your deployment as it may not always be possible to build a clean dependency order to create the objects.

Answer (score 1):

In a SQL Script after your CREATE you could check ALL_ERRORS (or dba_errors) for an error on that object and, if errors exist, EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to drop it.

e.g.)

```
set serveroutput on

create or replace procedure meowner.testproc
as
begin
  select;
end;
/

DECLARE
  x number;
begin  
   select count(*) into x from all_errors
   where  owner = 'MEOWNER' and NAME='TESTPROC' ;
   if x != 0 then
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP PROCEDURE meowner.testproc';
      dbms_output.put_line('Dropped due to compile error');
   end if;
end;
/

PROCEDURE TESTPROC compiled
Errors: check compiler log
Dropped due to compile error
anonymous block completed
```

Answer (score 0):

There's none, as far as I can tell. A stored procedure will be created in invalid state.

Though, you could try to create a *wrapper* procedure which would

- create a procedure
- check its status
- drop it if it is *invalid*

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Let me go and research about _**wrapper**_ procedure